# Angular how to do multiple open and close

Tags: javascript, angular

I want do if click to find all same id.

and all same id's isOpen together becomes true.

How to do that?

html

```
<div  *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <div class="open-close-container" (click)="test(card)">
      <div *ngIf="card.isOpen">test</div>
      <div *ngIf="!card.isOpen">shidsfsdfsdf<br>t</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ts

```
 cards = [{name:'div1',id: 1,isOpen: false},{name:'div2',id: 1 ,isOpen: false},{name:'div1',id: 2,isOpen: false},{name:'div2',id: 3 ,isOpen: false}];

  test(q){
    console.log(q)
        q.isOpen = !q.isOpen
  }
```

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adjxmb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: please share your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `test(q)` function change the `q.isOpen = !q.isOpen` to:

```
test(q){
    this.cards.filter((card) => q.id == card.id).map((q) =>{ q.isOpen = !q.isOpen});    
}
```

Essentially, when you invoke the `test()` the card array is filtered with the matching `id` and only those objects are changed to have `q.isOpen = !q.isOpen`.

Here is the modified [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ushxqw?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

change your test() to:

```
    test(c){
    for (let card in this.cards)
        if(cards[card].id == c.id)
            cards[card].isOpen = !cards[card].isOpen
}
```